# Import image to a component from React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, asynchronous

I'm building an app with React and Typescript.

I'm retrieving data using a free API. I'm trying to use a default image for the objects that do not have them.

This is the structure of my project:

[image: Structure of the project]

In `movies.service.tsx` I fetch the data and assign to the property **picture** of **movie object** the value retrieved from the DB (in case there is no value, I would like to assign it the path of `default-poster.png`):

```
import * as img from '../images/default-poster.png';

console.log('img ', img);

const movieApiBaseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
const posterBaseUrl = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300";
export interface Movie {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    rating: number;
    description: string;
    picture?: string;
    date: string;
  }

  export function fetchMovies(): Promise<Movie[]> {
   return fetch(
     `${movieApiBaseUrl}/discover/movie?sort_by=year.desc&api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
   )
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((res) => mapResult(res.results))
     .catch(() => {
         return [];
     });
 }

 // = movie has to be after const {} here
 function mapResult(res: any[]): Movie[] {
   return res.map((movie) => {
     const {
       id,
       title,
       vote_average,
       overview,
       poster_path,
       date,
     } = movie;
     return {
       id: id,
       title: title,
       rating: vote_average,
       description: overview,
       picture: poster_path ? `${posterBaseUrl}${poster_path}` : img,
       date: date,
     };
   });
 }
```

However, I was not allowed to assign img to picture property by Typescript. I have also consoled out img value and it is equal to a module:

```
Module default: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA <...>" Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module" esModule: true __proto: Object
```

I need to assign the paths of images to `picture` property so that I could use them in `MovieCards.tsx` component later on.

What should I change?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you simply use this value instead of img `'../images/default-poster.png'`

Comment: when the path does not get assigned to the  `picture` property since in `MovieCards.tsx` component in which I use the paths of images

Comment: Then try adding '../../images/default-poster.png'

Comment: I've done it and I also made sure the paths are displayed in the screen from `MovieCards.tsx`, so the values of the paths are passed to `MovieCards.tsx` correctly but for some reason '../../images/default-poster.png' does not show the image from react app

Comment: I've also did `import '../../images/default-poster.png';` inside `MovieCards.tsx` but it did not help either

Comment: Eventually I've found a solution - assigned '../images/no-image-available.png' import to a variable and then then passed the variable noImage as the third operand of ternary operator `picture: poster_path ? `${posterBaseUrl}${poster_path}` : noImage`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is importing the default image to `movies.service.tsx`:

`import noImage from '../images/no-image-available.png';`

and then passing the variable `noImage` as the third operand of ternary operator:
`` picture: poster_path ? `${posterBaseUrl}${poster_path}` : noImage, ``